# how works dojo class object

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis

I have declared a dojo class and confused a bit.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
    "config/commonConfig",
    "esri/SpatialReference",
    "esri/geometry/Extent",
    "esri/geometry/Point"],
function (declare,config, SpatialReference, Extent, Point) {

    var wgs1984 = new SpatialReference({ "wkt": config.wktWgs1984 });

    return declare("modules.utils", null, {
        wgs1984: wgs1984,
    });
});
```

I created varibles named **wgs1984** out of the class and referenced in class. Is there a difference the following three stuations:

```
  var wgs1984 = new SpatialReference({ "wkt": config.wktWgs1984 });

  return declare("modules.utils", null, {
            wgs1984: wgs1984,
  });
  Is this call gives same instance on memory each time?
```

and

```
 return declare("modules.utils", null, {
            wgs1984: new SpatialReference({ "wkt": config.wktWgs1984 })
  }); 
  Is this call create new instance on memory?
```

and

```
 return declare("modules.utils", null, {
            wgs1984: SpatialReference({ "wkt": config.wktWgs1984 })
  });
```

Is this call create new instance on memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example the SpatialReference will be created once when the module is loaded. All of your instances of modules.utils will point to the same object.

In the second case the SpatialReference is created each time you instantiate a modules.utils  object. Each utils object will have a separate SpatialReference.

Third case does not make sense. I'm not sure what the result would be.

The second case is what you would do most of the time, but there are cases for using the first example.

edit:

If you want to create new SpatialReferences each time wgs84 is called you need to use a function.

```
declare("utils",[],{
   wgs84: function(){ return new SpatialReference(...);}
})


var obj = new utils();

var instance1 = obj.wgs84();
var instance2 = obj.wgs84();
```

instance1 and instance2 are not the same object.

Comment: I think for second case, if I create one instance of module.utils  and call two times it, I will have two different SpatialReference. var obj = new modüle.utils(); and var ins1 = obj.wgs84; var ins2 =obj.wgs84; ins1 and ins2 are different objects. Is this true?

Comment: @bookmarker, not exactly. When you create obj, wgs84 will be set to a SpatialReference. If you want to create new SpatialReferences, set wgs84 to a function like this wgs84: function() {return new SpatialReference()}. Now everytime you call obj.wgs84 you will get a new object. I have editted my answer to show this clearer.